# Post request in HTTP and HTTPS protocol

Tags: http, ssl, https, http-post, http-get

We are trying to make a secure communication between our embedded system and web server.Firstly we implement HTTP connection to in our microcontroller. I am just connecting to 80 port of my web server and send simple GET request to this port as example below :

```
GET /foo.php?msg=test HTTP/1.1
HOST: foo.com
```

My questions is,How we will turn this to HTTPS ? Which port i should connect ?
 Will be any difference on structure of GET request above ? Will i have to do some encryption manually or connect to "https" link instead "http" is enuogh for secure communication.

Thanks for any information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between a HTTP request and a HTTPS request is that the first is send over a plain TCP connection while the other is send over a TLS connection, i.e.:

- with HTTP you establish a TCP connection and send the request over this connection
- with HTTPS you establish a TCP connection, **upgrade this connection to TLS (including proper certificate validation etc!)** and then send the same request as you did with HTTP over this connection.

Apart from that I recommend to either use an established library for HTTP or carefully read the [standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616). **Although HTTP looks simply it is actually not** and there are many questions here where users try to do a simply HTTP request and trip over behavior they did not expect.

For example in your case the server might send the response with chunked encoding, with content-length or simply end it with connection close. And it might wait for further requests on the same connection since HTTP/1.1 implicitly enables HTTP keep-alive. Does your code really account for all these cases?

Comment: After we get response from server. we are closing communication manually.

Comment: @user3077756: and how do you know when the server is done sending the response?

Comment: Below example of our server response.

+IPD,343:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-Powered-By-Plesk: PleskWin
Date: Thu, 22 Jun 2017 08:46:25 GMT
Content-Length: 154

{
 "success": 1
}

When I see "success" i know server responsed me. This handles most cases. For other cases we implement other connection handle mechanism on both embedded and server side.

Comment: I see. You are actually assuming a very specific server behavior, i.e. not generic HTTP processing. Hopefully you have full control over the server too so that the server specific assumption you make will never change.

Comment: Super old question but this is pretty much the only thing I could find that is relevant to my current problem: I am trying to send a POST request over HTTPS [but it doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77804811/server-post-request-works-with-http-but-not-with-https-error-routinespacket-l). I get errors like, `packet too long` or `wrong ssl version`. The simple HTTP version works, but not HTTPS. I am at wits end and have no clue as to how to even debug this further. Any ideas?